# Converting a POST request with URLEncodedFormEntity using deprecated Apache HTTP client into a request using Retrofit with @FormUrlEncoded on Android

Tags: android, http, retrofit

I'm trying to upgrade some of the code in my application to use Retrofit over the recently deprecated org.apache.http.client classes and I've run into an issue.

The old implementation detailed below works just fine - It successfully logs in:

```
public void postRequest(String username, String password) {
   List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = getNameValuePairs(username, password);

    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, HTTP_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, HTTP_SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(LOGIN_POST_URL);
    httpPost.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
}


private List<NameValuePair> getNameValuePairs(String username, String password) {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserName", username));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", password));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ReturnUrl", "https://myapi.com/security_check"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("AppId", APP_ID));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Sign in", "Sign in"));
    return nameValuePairs;
}
```

This implementation using Retrofit does not (I call this with the appropriate params):

```
   public interface MyLoginApi {
      String LOGIN_BASE_URL = "https://myapi.com";
      String USER_AGENT = "my_user_agent";

      @FormUrlEncoded
      @POST("/login")
      @Headers("User-Agent: " + USER_AGENT)
      void login(@Field("UserName") final String username, @Field("Password") final String password, @Field("ReturnUrl") String returnUrl, @Field("AppId") String appId, @Field("Sign in") String signIn, Callback<Object> callback);
}
```

In addition to the above, I've also tried using a request interceptor on the RestAdapter but this also provided the same result:

```
@Override
public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
    request.addEncodedPathParam("UserName", credentials.getUsername());
    request.addEncodedPathParam("Password", credentials.getPassword());
    request.addEncodedPathParam("ReturnUrl", "https://myapi.com/security_check");
    request.addEncodedPathParam("AppId", APP_ID);
    request.addEncodedPathParam("Sign in", "Sign in");
}
```

I perform the request using Retrofit like this:

```
MyLoginApi api = new RestAdapter.Builder()
.setEndpoint("https://myapi.com/")
.build()
.create(MyLoginApi.class);
api.login(username, password, returnUrl, appId, "Sign In", this);
```

This makes the request but the login is unsuccessful.
Have I misunderstood the @FormUrlEncoded annotation? Is there a mechanism in Retrofit that facilitates such requests?

Comment: the intercept is unrelated to your problem (and path params are not what you use). Your interface looks right, except may be for the `Sign in` fields, it is a bit weird to have a space in a field name. The problem is probably with the return type in the callback. I doubt you want an Object. Show how you create the adapter and call the login method.

Comment: @njzk2 It is strange to have the space in the field name, however the existing apache client implementation works just fine. I definitely don't want an Object - but I'm looking at the logs for the time being to see that my login request is made successfully before solving any subsequent problems!

Comment: you should add `.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)` on your adapter builder to see all that goes in and out of retrofit

Comment: @njzk2 yes, I have done in my real implementation. That's how I can see the success it failure output.

Answer (score 0):

I just falled into exactly what you wrote above.

From what I see, your code looks alright. The only thing worries me is probably that space between in `Sign In` in `@Field("Sign In")`
Not sure if it's related, you can refer to https://github.com/square/retrofit/commit/4c38147577d47227b05c0bdb0e8bfefd0f995dec

Anyway, I'll leave my implementation below for your reference.

Old implementation

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(loginUrl);
post.setHeader("app-token", appToken);
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
HttpEntity respEntity = response.getEntity();  
...
```

Converted to Retrofit Implementation

API Singleton Class

```
public class ApiClient {
  private static Context sContext = Application.getAppContext();
  private static String API_URL = sContext.getString(R.string.url);
  private static String APP_TOKEN = sContext.getString(R.string.app_token);

  private static ApiClientInterface sApiClientInterface;

  public static final int REQUEST_SUCCESS = 200;

  public static ApiClientInterface getServiceClient() {
    if (sApiClientInterface == null) {
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                        request.addHeader("app-token", APP_TOKEN);
                    }
                })
                .setEndpoint(API_URL)
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).setLog(new AndroidLog("Retrofit"))
                .build();

        sApiClientInterface = restAdapter.create(ApiClientInterface.class);
    }

    return sApiClientInterface;
  }

  public interface ApiClientInterface {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/login")
    void login(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password, Callback<JsonObject> responseCallback);
  }
}
```

Usage

```
ApiClient.getServiceClient().login(username, password, new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void success(JsonObject jsonObject, Response response) {
                if (response.getStatus() == ApiClient.REQUEST_SUCCESS) {
                    // do something
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                   // do something
            }
        });
```

PS: It's a good practice to have your API implementation as singleton, so that each API request won't be recreated over and over again during the app lifecycle.